# What is the purpose of form in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React JS and when I started to learn about forms in React JS, I felt like why we need form concept(`<form></form>`)in React JS, since React JS is unidirectional we won't able to submit any action in form. Can anyone help to understand the purpose of forms?

Comment: The HTML `form` element is rather unrelated to React `form` elements represent a document section containing interactive controls for submitting information.. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: In addition to what @DrewReese said, it is semantically correct in HTML to wrap inputs that are meant to be submitted in `form` tags. You can easily [serialize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) the inputs and even submit them with standard HTML (no JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your form asynchronously using event handlers. It's basically like a wrapper that you put on a group of inputs that you consider to be all of the inputs that you need for a single request (or "submission").

Check out this article from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for answering, but even without form also we can make asynchronously calls know

Comment: @Pumpkinbell That's true, but if you want to do something like sending a file to a server, you'll probably want to use something like `FormData`. How to: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/formdata-explained/ Docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects